# How to resize slider images according to screens

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am using Basic-slider in my project http://basic-slider.com/ as a background slider. I want to make images resize according to different windows. I am using some code but don't know whether I am right or not, as I am not familiar with javascript and jquery

Original script provided was:-

```
<script class="secret-source">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#banner-slide').bjqs({
animtype      : 'slide',
height        : 800,
width         : 1349,
responsive    : true,
randomstart   : true
});
});    
</script>
```

I modified it according to my requirement as below

```
<script class="secret-source">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

var h = screen.availHeight;
  var w = screen.availWidth;

$('#banner-slide').bjqs({
animtype      : 'slide',
height        : h,
width         : w,
responsive    : true,
randomstart   : true
});
});    
</script>
```

It's not working and am not sure this code is proper or not.

Please can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work, because what if someone resizes their browser after the page loads? Then it'll be the wrong size again.

In any case, most sliders aren't made to be full screen, and the particular slider you've mentioned is intentionally minimal, and therefore not a good fit for doing anything non-standard with.

A quick google search for "full screen background slider" brings up this: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ which looks like a much better fit for you. It automatically handles the full screen, and resizing - see the demo at http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

Good luck!

(PS - you may be using CakePHP as a framework, but this specific problem has nothing to do with CakePHP - I've retagged it as jquery / carousel)